# How to search in a plist to retrieve a value for a specific key

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I am using a plist to store the country data for my app's users. So I have this `<dict>` list that holds several **countries**. For each country there are several **provinces**. For each region there are **regions**. And each region holds many **cities**.

So my list looks like the following:

```
<dict>
    <key>Country</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ISO</key>
            <string>ES</string>
            <key>Value</key>
            <string>Spain</string>
            <key>Children</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>ISO</key>
                    <string>AL</string>
                    <key>Value</key>
                    <string>Andalucia</string>
                    <key>Children</key>
                    <array>
                        ...
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

The most detailed node is the city which holds information as:

```
<dict>
    <key>ISO</key>
    <string>03002</string>
    <key>Value</key>
    <string>ALICANTE</string>
</dict>
```

In the database I then store **03002** which is the unique key for **Alicante** in this case. But in my GUI I obviously want to display Alicante and not the numeric representation.

**So is there an easy way to search this plist file to find the matching Value for this ISO ?**

Thanks!

**EDIT**

At the moment I created this method. It does the trick, but I cannot really call it efficient coding. So please advise...

```
- (NSString *)getCityNameForKey: (NSString *)ISO {
    NSString *cityName = @"";
    NSArray *citySource = [[Locations getInstance] toDataSource];

    for (int i = 0; i < [citySource count]; i++) {
        //Country
        NSDictionary *p_dictionary = [citySource objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *provinces = [p_dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
        if ([provinces count] > 0) {
            //Province
            for (int j = 0; j < [provinces count]; j++) {
                NSDictionary *r_dictionary = [provinces objectAtIndex:j];
                NSArray *regions = [r_dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
                if ([regions count] > 0) {
                    //City
                    for (int k = 0; k < [regions count]; k++) {
                        NSDictionary *c_dictionary = [regions objectAtIndex:k];
                        NSArray *cities = [c_dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
                        if ([cities count] > 0) {
                            for (int l = 0; l < [cities count]; l++) {
                                NSDictionary *result_dict = [cities objectAtIndex:l];
                                if ([[result_dict objectForKey:@"ISO"] isEqualToString:ISO]) {

                                    index_country = i;
                                    index_province = j;
                                    index_region = k;
                                    index_city = l;                                    

                                    cityName = [result_dict objectForKey:@"Value"];
                                    return cityName;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cityName;
}
```

Comment: How deep does the nesting of children go?

Comment: As said there's Country -> Province -> Region -> City. That's what makes it complicated imo. Because I don't know in which region, province or country a specific city is located if I just have the ISO value...

Answer (score 3):

You can load a plist into an `NSDictionary` with the method:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then simply access the values as you would for any dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *region = [dict valueForKey:@"City"];
NSString *name = [region objectForKey:@"Value"];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough data for me to really picture it exactly, but you could use a keyPath to get an array of all Cities and then use a predicate on this array

Something like this would be a start for how you start to get all the data into one array

```
NSArray *cities = [countries valueForKeyPath:@"Children.Children"];
```

Then to search you could do something like

```
__block NSString *name = nil;

[cities enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([[obj valueForKey:@"ISO"] isEqualToString:ISOValue]) {
        name = [obj valueForKey:@"Value"];
        *stop = YES:
    }
}];
```