# how to search specific data in plist ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

Hello I believe that this is a simple issue, I'm a newbie in objective c so please help me.
I have a populated data in plist and i want to make a simple search ( uitextfield and uibutton) how will i make this? Here's my plist:

```
     <plist version="1.0">
     <array>
         <dict>
             <key>ID</key>
             <integer>0</integer>
             <key>title</key>
             <string>Toyota Gen. Santos</string>
             <key>address</key>
             <string>National Hwy., City Heights, General Santos City, South Cotabato</string>
             <key>tel</key>
             <string>(083) 554 2994</string>
             <key>latitude</key>
             <real>6.119086</real>
             <key>longitude</key>
             <real>125.159881</real>
             <key>img</key>
             <string>locator_gmap_marker.png</string>
        </dict>
        ....
    </array>
    </plist>
```

Thanks! Here's my method for loading plist

```
    //read plist
    -(NSString *) dataFilePath{
         NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
         return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locations.plist"];
    }

    - (void)readPlist{
         //read plist
         NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
         if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
         NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
         NSLog(@"%@\n",array);
         }
    }
```

The [self readPlist] will be placed at the veiwDidLoad method. the output will be seen  at the NSLOG - all item I have stored in the plist. What i hope to achieved is to get a specific data by searcheing on a UITextfield with a UIbutton and will be seen at a UIlabel.

This code to iterate the dictionaries from the plist i got it from this [How to search in a plist to retrieve a value for a specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965433/how-to-search-in-a-plist-to-retrieve-a-value-for-a-specific-key), here's the code from event button:

```
   //event button
   //Read locations details from plist
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"locations" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

   for (NSDictionary *row in locations){
        NSNumber *tel = [row objectForKey:@"tel"];
        NSNumber *address = [row objectForKey:@"address"];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];

        self.titleLbl.text = title;
        self.addrsLbl.text = address;
        self.telLbl.text = tel;
   }
```

Comment: Start with code to load the array. Do you have that? Then, do you know how to iterate the array? Do you know how to look in each dictionary?

Comment: OK, good start. Now post some code that attempts to iterate the dictionaries in the array.

Comment: OK, you have the hard part done. What part do you still need help with? Just keep working on it step by step. Next is seeing of the dictionary contains a certain value. Then base that value on the value in a text field.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy i think I have the idea now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code i remade in event button. Thanks to 
Bijoy Thangaraj, Tark for reference and rmaddy for helping out.

[How to search in a plist to retrieve a value for a specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965433/how-to-search-in-a-plist-to-retrieve-a-value-for-a-specific-key)

[Search on Arrays inside Plist in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292876/search-on-arrays-inside-plist-in-xcode)

```
 - (IBAction)eventSearch:(UIButton *)sender {
     //Read locations details from plist
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"locations" ofType:@"plist"];
     NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

     //convert string to number
     NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
     NSNumber *IDnum = [f numberFromString:self.idTxtField.text];

     for (NSDictionary *row in locations) {

          NSNumber *itemID = [row objectForKey:@"ID"];

          if(IDnum == itemID){
             NSString *tel = [row objectForKey:@"tel"];
             NSString *address = [row objectForKey:@"address"];
             NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];

             self.titleLbl.text = title;
             self.addLbl.text = address;
             self.telLbl.text = tel;
          }
     }
     NSLog(@"accessed!");
     self.idTxtField.text = @"";
 }
```